# Formatting the value that the option "Labeled" shows to the right of a manipulator

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I need that the appearence labeled of the manipulate take the form rationalize. My code is:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Cos@x, {x, 0, 10}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Point[{t, Cos[t]}]}], {{t, 0}, 0, 10, 1,
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Something like:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[Cos@x, {x, 0, 10}, Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Point[{t, 
   Cos[t]}]}], {{t, 0}, 0, 10, 1,   Appearance -> \[Pi] Rationalize[2]}]
```

I am working in this code:

```
[![Manipulate\[
 Grid\[{{Graphics\[{Circle\[{0, 0}, 5\], Blue, PointSize\[.04\], 
      Style\[Text\[
        "Q", {4.4 Cos\[\[Theta\] + \[Pi\]/2\], 
         4.4 Sin\[\[Theta\] + \[Pi\]/2\]}\], Black, Bold \] , 
      Point\[{5 Cos\[\[Theta\] + \[Pi\]/2\], 5 Sin\[\[Theta\] + \[Pi\]/2\]}\]}, 
     Axes -> True\], 
    Plot\[-5 Cos\[x\], {x, 0, 11}, 
     Ticks -> {Range\[0, 11\], Range\[-5, 5, 2\]}, 
     PlotLabel -> 
      Style\["x(t)= A Cos(\[Omega\]t+\[Theta\])", Black, Bold\], 
     AxesLabel -> {t\[s\], X\[cm\]}, ImageSize -> 350, 
     Epilog -> {Red, 
       Line\[{{\[Theta\], 0}, {\[Theta\], -5 Cos\[\[Theta\]\]}}\], {Black, 
        Dashed, Line\[{{0, 5}, {10, 5}}\]},
       {Black, Dashed, Line\[{{0, -5}, {10, -5}}\]}, PointSize\[.025\], 
       Point\[{\[Theta\], -5 Cos\[\[Theta\]\]}\] , 
       Style\[Text\["Q", {\[Theta\] + .35, -5.4 Cos\[\[Theta\]\]}\], Black, 
        Bold \]            }\]}}, 
  Frame -> All\], {{\[Theta\], 0, "Position(\[Theta\])"}, 0, 11, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, SaveDefinitions -> True\]][1]][1]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand maybe, but would `{{t, 0}, 0, 10*Pi, Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}` do what you seek?

Comment: Or maybe this? Manipulate[
 Plot[Cos@x, {x, 0, 10}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Point[{t, Cos[t]}]}], {{t, 0}, 0, 10, 
  1/10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}] or do you mean this: Appearance -> {\[Pi] Rationalize[2], "Labeled"}}

Comment: I get it !!!!! is this  {{\[Theta], 0, "tiempo(t)"}, 0, 3 Pi, Pi/2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}

Comment: @Andres It's perfectly ok to post your solution in the preceding comment as an answer below.

Comment: Thanks my friend @Michael E2 and you @ bill s.Your comments helped me to notice my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy. Just make your own version of a manipulator control.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[Cos @ x, {x, 0, 3 π}, Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Point[{t, Cos[t]}]}],
  Row[{Control[{t, 0, 3 π, .1 π}], "  " , Dynamic[Rationalize[t/π]], "π"}]]
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Perfect @m_goldberg, this code has implicit step of 0.1.Thanks.

Comment: @Andres. No, it imposes an ***explicit*** step of `0.1 π`. You can change that to any step size you like.

Comment: @Andres. You have asked a number of questions and received good answers for which you have left thank-you notes in comments. On Stack Exchange sites that is not the preferred behavior; better to upvote and, in the case of the best answer, accept. Please read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)